# Calculating height of the child component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm developing an Angular application and I'm facing some issues.

I am in a situation where I have to load multiple child components inside a parent container component.The child component is loaded one below the other. I want to load 'n' number of components till the scroll is visible so that I can handle lazy loading of child components. As of now, I'm trying to use the following condition.

```
while (window.screen.height > 
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height) 
   {
      this.child= this.childSet.slice(0, this.count+1);
   }
```

and the html code is as follows

```
<child*ngFor="let child of childSet" [value]="child " [column-size]="child .size ? child .size : 12"></child>
```

but it's going on in an infinite loop and I don't know why but I guess the view is not rendered as fast as the while loop. So how to resolve this issue.Please help.

Comment: Hi, Maciej, this sounds to me like a virtualized list job, there's a few implementation of this with really nice features, lazy load, container refresh and so on, please take a look at this package, http://rintoj.github.io/angular2-virtual-scroll if this not fit with your needs could you create a quick demo https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular best

Comment: This while loop can 2 things: loop 0 or infinite times, there is no other option. angular will not re-render while you are inside the loop except you tell him to do... Can you show where you are doing this while loop? thanks

Comment: Its in ngOnInit of the parent component

Answer (score 3):

I have created a demo that provides a solution to your issue. Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9hd2no.
Instead of using a loop, I put your logic inside an `interval` which will keep repeating till `stopCondition` is `true`. I have also added some classes in `styles.css` and `app.component.css` to make the parent component height grow as the number of child component increases. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using `trackBy` for you `*ngFor` this way it won't refresh all the elements and instead it will just add a new one whenever you change the collection. It can be a solution to your infinite loop.

I'd try something like this

```
  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
```

and the html

```
<child *ngFor="let child of childSet; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="child " [column-size]="child .size ? child .size : 12"></child>
```

Answer (score 2):

**GetBoundingClientRect** returns perfect value only after rendering finish. So
you should render one element at a time and append element only if scroll is not visible.